# Access Postgres database in pgAdmin3 for user without password

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I have created user in PostgreSQL database that don't have password.

When I tried to connect to same user in pgAdmin3 it asks for password for the user every time I want to connect to server.

what i did was following:sudo vi /etc/postgresql/10.2/main/pg_hba.conf # Add following lines above first uncommented line # Allow user login without password # TYPE DATABASE USER ADDRESS METHOD local all user trust # Save file and restart Postgresql sudo service postgresql restart

How to access database for user without password in pgAdmin3?
What are the config changes required in pgAdmin3?

Comment: See if this may be of help: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8111/pgadmin-iii-how-to-connect-to-database-when-password-is-empty

Comment: Are you connecting without a password for the same user via different client like **psql**?

Comment: i have created a user whose password is empty in postgres and created database under that user .Now i want to access database under the created user

Comment: the link you provided is not helpful

Comment: Probably unrelated, but: an "empty password" is something different than "no password".

Comment: what i did was following:sudo vi /etc/postgresql/10.2/main/pg_hba.conf      # Add following lines above first uncommented line      # Allow user login without password     # TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD     local   all             user                                trust      # Save file and restart Postgresql     sudo service postgresql restart

Comment: sudo vi /etc/postgresql/10.2/main/pg_hba.conf     in that made : DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD     local   all             user                                trust

Comment: to remove password for user .now when i am trying to access that user in pgadmin i am unable to do that

Comment: You should get your story straight in the question. Do edit it and attach additional information on what you have tried, to keep it all together instead of separate comments. It seems like you've tried some things. Share it.

Comment: Okay thanks kamil G .i will do it soon